# linux find command to keep only .h files

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I have a source tree have lots files with different file types.
The source tree has many sub folders.
How do i keep the folder structure of the source tree and delete all files besides .h files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` with negated predicates for this. Basically, make a command that finds all the files that you want to keep, negate the matching condition(s) (such that it now matches the files you *don't* want to keep), and tell it to either delete those files or simply move them out of the way.

For example, this command will print a list of all files under the current directory, including subdirectories, that have names that end in `.h`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.h' -print
```

(The `-type f` restricts the match to regular files only; not directories, device nodes, and so on. The quoting around `*.h` is important.)

Now, invert the name condition to print all the files that do *not* have names that end in `.h`:

```
find . -type f -not -name '*.h' -print
```

(Note that `-not` is not POSIX compliant, but it is cleaner here since it doesn't require shell escaping. You can also use the POSIX standard `!` instead, but at least bash requires that `!` is escaped.)

**Once you are satisfied** that the list of files matches what you want to delete, simply replace `-print` with `-delete` to actually delete the files. Or, if you need a POSIX solution (again), you can use `-exec rm '{}' '+'` instead of `-delete`, at the cost of invoking `rm` an unknown number of times.

Comment: Great thanks! Is there any good method to delete the folders with no files in ?

Comment: I think I know how to do it "find . -empty -type d -print"

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that with one simple command:

```
find . -not -name *.h -exec rm -r "{}" \;
```

If you want to make sure it will delete what you indeed want, you can remove the `-exec` part and just add the `-print` flag to see what matches. Once you're sure, you can append the `-exec rm -r "{}" \;` part.